# How to move the XML namespaces to a specific parent node (not the root node) in XML output in Mule 4.4.0

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am trying to create below XML in mulesoft 4.4.0 using dataweave script.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<batch>
  <nsA:parent xmlns:nsA="http://www.testA.com/core" xmlns:nsB="http://www.testB.com/core">
    <nsB:child >ChildNodeValue</nsB:child>
  </nsA:parent>
</batch>
```

**Dataweave scripts I tried are :**

**1st Try:**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns nsA http://www.testA.com/core
ns nsB http://www.testB.com/core

---
batch: {
    (payload map ((item, index) -> {
        nsA#parent:{
            nsB#child:"ChildNodeValue"
        }
    })
 )}


-------------------------------------

Output:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<batch>
  <nsA:parent xmlns:nsA="http://www.testA.com/core">
    <nsB:child xmlns:nsB="http://www.testB.com/core">ChildNodeValue</nsB:child>
  </nsA:parent>
</batch>
```

**2nd try:** : Using writeDeclaredNamespaces="All"

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml writeDeclaredNamespaces="All"
ns nsA http://www.testA.com/core
ns nsB http://www.testB.com/core

---
batch: {
    (payload map ((item, index) -> {
        nsA#parent:{
            nsB#child:"ChildNodeValue"
        }
    })
 )}


---------------------------
Output:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<batch xmlns:nsA="http://www.testA.com/core" xmlns:nsB="http://www.testB.com/core">
  <nsA:parent>
    <nsB:child>ChildNodeValue</nsB:child>
  </nsA:parent>
</batch>
```

**How can I move the namespaces to a specific parent node (not the root node) in XML output?**

Thank you

Comment: By default DataWeave will emit the namespaces in the first node that use them, which is compatible with XML standards. Why do you need to select a specific node?

Comment: Thanks, The requirement is because of my downstream system (which is not in my control) takes xml in this format only.

Comment: Then be aware that the downstream system is not fully compliant with the XML Schema standard.

Comment: @aled Thanks, Yes, That makes sense.  I will check with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to define the namespaces as attributes like below.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
batch: {
    "nsA:parent" @(
        "xmlns:nsA": "http://www.testA.com/core",
        "xmlns:nsB": "http://www.testB.com/core"
    ):{
        "nsB:child":"ChildNodeValue"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, adding namespace as attributes and writing nides in double quotes solved the issue

Comment: This works for me too, but I use a different syntax for the namespace.  I add the namespace declaration in the header, and I use nsA#parent without quotes for the element name.  This still needs the xmlns attributes to be added, but the value can use the namespace reference from the header